# Linux join utility complains about input file not being sorted

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, join, text-processing

I have two files:

file1 has the format:

```
field1;field2;field3;field4
```

(file1 is initially unsorted)

file2 has the format:

```
field1
```

(file2 is sorted)

I run the 2 following commands:

```
sort -t\; -k1 file1 -o file1 # to sort file 1
join -t\; -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 file1 file2
```

I get the following message:

```
join: file1:27497: is not sorted: line_which_was_identified_as_out_of_order
```

Why is this happening ?

(I also tried to sort file1 taking into consideration the entire line not only the first filed of the line but with no success)

`sort -t\; -c file1` doesn't output anything. Around line 27497, the situation is indeed strange which means that sort doesn't do its job correctly:

```
              XYZ113017;...
line 27497--> XYZ11301;...
              XYZ11301;...
```

Comment: `join` is extremely picky. What does `sort -t\; -c file1` say?  What's around line 27497 of the sorted file? (Please [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25431673/edit) your question with these details.)

Answer (score 12):

To complement [Wumpus Q. Wumbley's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25432076/45375) with a broader perspective (since I found this post researching a slightly different problem).

- When **using `join`**, the **input files must be sorted *by the join field ONLY***, otherwise you may see the warning reported by the OP.

There are two **common scenarios in which *more* than the field of interest is *mistakenly* included when sorting** the input files:

- If you do specify a field, it's **easy to forget that you must also specify a *stop* field - even if you target only *1* field** - because `sort` uses the remainder of the line if only a *start* field is specified; e.g.:

  - `sort -t, -k1 ...   # !! FROM field 1 THROUGH THE REST OF THE LINE`
  - `sort -t, -k1,1 ... # Field 1 only`
- If your **sort field is the FIRST field in the input**, it's **tempting to not specify any field selector at all**.

  - However, if field values can be prefix substrings of each other, **sorting whole lines will NOT (necessarily) result in the same sort order as just sorting by the 1st field**:
  - `sort ... # NOT always the same as 'sort -k1,1'! see below for example`

**Pitfall example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Input data: fields separated by '^'.
# Note that, when properly sorting by field 1, the order should
# be "nameA" before "nameAA" (followed by "nameZ").
# Note how "nameA" is a substring of "nameAA".
read -r -d '' input <<EOF
nameA^other1
nameAA^other2
nameZ^other3
EOF

# NOTE: "WRONG" below refers to deviation from the expected outcome
#       of sorting by field 1 only, based on mistaken assumptions.
#       The commands do work correctly in a technical sense.

echo '--- just sort'
sort <<<"$input" | head -1 # WRONG: 'nameAA' comes first

echo '--- sort FROM field 1'
sort -t^ -k1 <<<"$input" | head -1 # WRONG: 'nameAA' comes first

echo '--- sort with field 1 ONLY'
sort -t^ -k1,1 <<<"$input" | head -1 # ok, 'nameA' comes first
```

Explanation:

- When NOT limiting sorting to the first field, it is the relative sort order of chars. `^` and `A` (column index 6) that matters in this example. In other words: *the field separator is compared to data*, which is the source of the problem: `^` has a HIGHER ASCII value than `A`, and therefore sorts *after* 'A', resulting in the line starting with `nameAA^` sorting BEFORE the one with `nameA^`.
- Note: **It is possible for problems to surface on *one* platform, but be masked on *another***, based on locale and character-set settings and/or the `sort` implementation used; e.g., with a locale of `en_US.UTF-8` in effect, with `,` as the separator and `-` permissible inside fields:

  - `sort` as used on OSX 10.10.2 (which is an *old* GNU `sort` version, 5.93) sorts `,` before `-` (in line with ASCII values)
  - `sort` as used on Ubuntu 14.04 (GNU `sort` 8.21) does the *opposite*: sorts `-` before `,`<sup>[1]</sup>

<sup>[1] I don't know why - if somebody knows, please tell me. Test with `sort <<<$'-\n,'`</sup>

Answer (score 11):

`sort -k1` uses all fields starting from field 1 as the key. You need to specify a stop field.

```
sort -t\; -k1,1
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and I get exactly the same problem

Comment: can you copy those 3 lines around line 27497 into a separate file, and run `sort --debug -t\; -k1,1` on it, to see what order it chooses and why?

Comment: the debug output shows that sort identifies correctly the sorting field. still, it says that : 113017 comes before 11301 which is not the case

Comment: Try it this way: `LC_ALL=C sort --debug -s -t\; -k1,1 your3linefile`

Comment: yes that solves the problem. But I don't get it why is using simple byte comparison different from en_US.UTF-8 (I have only ascii charactes in my file)

Comment: actually it doesn't solve the problem, on the real file I get the same error but further down in the file.

Comment: The `join` man page recommends `-k 1b,1` for the sort key. The `b` would make a difference if there are any leading spaces.

Answer (score -4):

... or the gnu sort is just as buggy as every other GNU command

try and sort Gi1/0/11 vs Gi1/0/1 and you'll never be able to get an actual regular textual sort suitable for join input because someone added some extra intelligence in sort which will happily use numeric or human numeric sorting automagically in such cases without even bothering to add a flag to force the regular behavior

what is suitable for humans is seldom suitable for scripting