# How to grep multiple lines using a .txt vocab, matching only first word as variable?

Tags: grep

I'm trying to reduce a `.sm` `file1` - around 10 GB by filtering it using a fair long set of words (around 180.108 items) listed in a text file `file2`.

`File1` is structured as follows:

```
word <http://internet.address.com> 1
```

i.e. `one word` followed by `a blank space`, `an internet address`, and a `number`.

`File2` is a simple `.txt` file, a list of words, one on each line.

My aim is to create a third file `File3` containing only those lines in `file1` whose first word matches with the word-list of `file2`, and disregard the rest.

My attempt is the following:

```
grep -w -F -f file2.txt file1.sm > file3.sm
```

I've also attempted something along this line:

```
gawk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next } !($2 in a)' file2.txt  file1.sm > file3.sm
```

but with no success. I understand `/^` and `\b` might play a part here, but I don't know how to fit them in the syntax. I've looked around extensively but no solution seems to fit.

My problem is that here grep reads the entire file1's line, and it can happen that the matching word lies in the webpage address, which I'm not interested in finding out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` is the best tool for this, not `grep`/`awk`:

```
join -t' ' <(sort file1.sm) <(sort file2.txt) >file3.sm
```

Comment: I'm getting this error join: /dev/fd/63:14: is not sorted (despite both files are sorted). I see it might be a matter of encoding or an issue of case-sensitivity. However neither calling for LANG=it_IT.utf8 nor specifying  'sort -f' and join -i seems to work...

Comment: Hmmm... Could be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431673/linux-join-utility-complains-about-input-file-not-being-sorted)... Try to specify `sort -t' ' -k1,1` as recommended there.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! So the final line goes `join -t' ' <(sort -t' ' -k1,1 file1.sm) <(sort -t' ' -k1,1 file2.txt) > file3.sm`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/^/^/' file2.txt | grep -f - file1.sm
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem of having grep reading the entire file1's line

Comment: What do you mean?